# Chrome status bar overlaps links

Tags: google-chrome, user-interface

Does anyone else have this issue?  I have a navigation bar at the bottom of my page.  It is position:fixed; so it stays at the bottom of the page always.

Chrome displays a status bar at the bottom of the page when you hover over a link... therefor, hovering over the footer links causes the status bar to overlap the link.  When this happens, you can't click the link.

I would greatly appreciate any suggestions as to how to fix this problem. Maybe some JS that forces the status bar to disappear?

Comment: It should move automatically to the right or outside of the window...

Comment: What OS/version? Looks like a Chrome bug.

Answer (score 0):

They will automatically disappear when the mouse is nearing it. but js to hide it complete i didn't think so maybe a extension can do this but not a website.